# Python sendto Error TypeError: must be str, not bytes

Tags: python

I've Looked At Other Answered Questions and The Only Solution I've Found Is That It needs to send it encoded. But I still receive this error whether or not this is encoded. Any ideas??? The commented lines are ones that I removed to make it function as intended. I'm new to this so hopefully this question made sense.(I'm Using Version 3.6)

```
Host = servershost
Port = 12345

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((Host, Port))
s.setblocking(0)

rT = threading.Thread(target=receiving, args=("RecvThread", s))
rT.start()

message = input(Username + ": ")
#s.sendto(message)
while message != 'q':
    if message != '':
         s.sendto(Username + message.encode('utf-8'), server)
    #tlock.aquire()
    message = input(Username + ': ')
    tlock.release()
    time.sleep(0.2)

shutdown = True
rT.Join()
s.close()
```

Comment: `Username` doesn't look like bytes to me.

Comment: full stacktrace please...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre                                                             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pov7230\Desktop\Notepad++\realchat.py", line 77, in <module>
    s.sendto(Username + message.encode('utf-8'), server)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socket` object needs a `bytes` (binary) object, not a string (at least in Python 3).

So, just encode both strings so the result is a `bytes` object:

```
s.sendto((Username + message).encode('utf-8'), server)
```